# How to resolve apt-get error IGN & redundancies in sources.list?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

My system info is as follows

```
mme@host:~/Downloads$ hostnamectl

Static hostname: host      
Icon name: computer-laptop
Chassis: laptop
Machine ID: 12242323423423
Boot ID: 545435435
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
```

When I run `apt-get update` I get two IGN errors:

```
mme@host:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for mme: 
Hit:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:3 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                        
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                
Get:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [63.0 kB]
Hit:8 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch Release                          
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Fetched 63.0 kB in 0s (69.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
mme@host:~/Downloads$
```

Now I'm wondering how to resolve this and if there are any redundancies with my repositories.
`/etc/apt/sources.list` does not include the google repository which I think is strange, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ign` messages aren’t errors, they’re just information. The `InRelease` file is optional and some repositories don’t carry it.

The Google repository is described in its own file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

There doesn’t appear to be any redundancy in your repositories, at least given the output above.